# Package DMwR has non zero exit status

Tags: r, ubuntu-16.04

On using install.packages("DMwR") it gives "package DMwR has non zero exit status".I wanted to use knnImputation function for which this package is required.I am currently using ubuntu 16.04.I need help for its installation.
The complete error stack on running install.packages("DMwR") is shown below:

```
install.packages("DMwR",dependencies = TRUE)
Installing package into ‘/home/saarthak/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘TTR’, ‘curl’, ‘quantmod’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/TTR_0.23-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 309683 bytes (302 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 302 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/curl_3.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 367047 bytes (358 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 358 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/quantmod_0.4-13.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 142084 bytes (138 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 138 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/DMwR_0.4.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1941361 bytes (1.9 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.9 MB

* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/saarthak/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/curl’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘curl’ is not available for package ‘TTR’
* removing ‘/home/saarthak/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/TTR’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘TTR’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘TTR’, ‘curl’ are not available for package ‘quantmod’
* removing ‘/home/saarthak/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/quantmod’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘quantmod’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘quantmod’ is not available for package ‘DMwR’
* removing ‘/home/saarthak/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/DMwR’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘DMwR’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpxYqT0S/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: This is not enough information to go on. My guess is that you are missing some dependency. Paste the entire error stack or better yet, search this site for that error. I would be willing to bet family farm that this has been resolved previously. Perhaps the answer or question may not pertain to the specific package, but that's immaterial.

Comment: I've pasted the error stack can you tell me know what's wrong ?

Comment: If you read the entire stack, you will notice that you're missing system package `curl`. There is even a message hinting how you can fetch it depending on which OS you are.

Comment: You were right thanks for the help.